# How to make 2 words stack on top of each other with screen size reduction

Tags: html, css

I have a div that is 100% screen width that has 2 words as a heading.  When I reduce the screen the words are not stacking to make them responsive.  What have I omitted?

```css
h1.name {
  font-size: 92px;
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .15em;
}

#heading {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<section id="heading">
  <h1 class="name">Peter Silveri</h1>
</section>
```

Comment: Your code does NOT demonstrate the issue you are seeing. Have you omitted some additional CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior of html is it stacks 2 words on each other so you need not add extra css properties for stacking

The below code works for me, take a look at other parts of your code:

```
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
    h1.name {
        font-size: 92px;
        padding-top: 60px;
        padding-bottom: 60px;
        text-align: center;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: .15em;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="heading">
        <h1 class="name">Peter Silveri</h1>
    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: thanks I have sorted it out, sometimes it is what you leave in not leave out